# How to change pitch of voice during a call in Android

Tags: android, asterisk, sip, voip, phone-call

I am working on an android app in which I want to implement voice changing functionality during a call. I have googled a lot and I found that it is only possible using **VOIP**.

I have a few questions about that task:

1. Although I found that it is only possible using **VOIP**, but still let me ask my doubt, can we change the pitch of voice during a call in Rooted or Non-rooted mobile, programmatically.
2. If this implemented using **VOIP**, then what I come to know is that we have to maintain a asterisk server for this. Then does the voice changing process happen on asterisk server or at mobile side and how?

Comment: _"can we change the pitch of voice during a call in Rooted or Non-rooted mobile , programatically."_ No, apps can't do that.

Comment: @mark: While I think the voice packets during a call would be walled off (for security reasons), do take a look at various voice call recorder apps. They record the voice during a call (both ways). If you can get access to the voice packets, it may be possible to change your voice.

Comment: @Sriram..Thanks for reply, yes I went threw the call recording apps also, they are recording voice threw microphones and speaker voices, these apps also not accessing voice packets. I think  Michael is right, it is not possible to modify voice during a GSM or CDMA call in android .

Answer (score 4):

You can do this on the server side with `Asterisk`. I do not know how you want your app to be structured, but if you go the `Asterisk` way, the app will become like a conference call. Like so:

1. You call a number (Asterisk server).
2. Asterisk server dials desired number.
3. Your voice packets are transformed on the server and sent on to the receiver.
4. If your telecom laws do not support it, the number that flashes on the receiver's phone will have to be the Asterisk server/exchanges.

Comment: @Sriram.. I am not getting 4th point, Please put some light on 4th point.

Comment: The Asterisk server will act as a man-in-the-middle. You call the asterisk server and the **asterisk server** calls the target number. if the server is calling the target number, the number that flashes on the phone will also be that of the server. Now it is possible to replace the the number flashing on the target's phone with yours (and not the servers). if this is possible or not will be decided by the telecom laws of your country or place of deployment.

Comment: @Sriram...I got it now, thanks for your wonderful explanation.

Comment: @mark: If this answer was helpful, an upvote would be nice. If it was what you were looking for, you might want to mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @ Sriram...yes sure...I have up-voted your answer, but I am not sure about your 4 point, because some voice changing apps in market provides us option to enter the number which to be showed on receiver's phone screen when we call them threw Asterisk. And please also tell me, does Asterisk allow to make a call on GSM and CDMA network, means suppose a mobile , which doesn't have our voip app install, would be able to receive call from Asterisk? Same as SKYPE is doing. Please clear my this doubt also. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You can call any type of phone (Landline/gsm/cdma) from Asterisk. If you can change the number you send from Asterisk, go ahead. I am not too sure you can mask the sender's number at the receiver.